# remove try except:pass block in python

Tags: python, atom-editor

is there a way to remove code like this

```
try:
 # some code
 # ...
except:pass
```

to only the code inside the `try` block ?

the reason is previous developer write where every code have this (it more than 1000+ lines and multiple files), thus any error in the code cannot be print out.

I tried manually using find and replace to change `try:` and `except:pass` to '' but it is exhausting, too time consuming and the problem with indent.

help .. this giving me a headache...

Comment: Just do a search and replace for `except:pass` and replace with `except Exception as _uniqueName: raise _uniqueName`

Comment: just find/replace `except:pass` with `except:raise`

Comment: @TemporalWolf  THANK YOU!!!! well if you add it to answer I'll mark it as answered, wonder why never think about that before :/

Comment: @whale_steward I added it with a comment.

Comment: weird cannot mark it as answered, maybe need to wait a few hours ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find/replace `except:pass` with `except:raise` if you need to fix a current bug.

Although eventually you're gonna have to bite the bullet and actually fix the code.

Comment: @whale_steward I agree. I think python IDEs/compilers should warn/ban the usage of `except:pass` unless you specify the error: `except KeyError: pass`. That is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Options vary a bit depending on what IDE and OS you're using. Here's a method that should work on Linux and Mac variants.

`grep -r "except:pass" -l * | xargs sed -i .bak 's/except:pass/except: import sys; print(sys.exc_info()[0])/g'`

The `grep` finds every file containing "except:pass" in the current folder or any subfolders, then passes this list of files to `sed`, which replaces the unhelpful code with a generic exception print statement.